# How to automate installation of software onto Azure VMs using VSTS DSC configurations

Tags: azure, automation, installation, azure-devops, dsc

All,

I am trying to figure out how to install software specifically TrendMicro onto Azure VMs using VSTS DSC configurations.  All i need is to be pointed in the right direction on how to accomplish this or suggestions.  I have very little experience doing this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use trendmicro extensionn

Answer (score 3):

To install software to Azure VM by PowerShell DSC, you can refer the document D[eploy your application on virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app).

As the example [Install an app to a Windows VM with PowerShell DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#install-an-app-to-a-windows-vm-with-powershell-dsc), the example powershell script as:

```
# Define the script for your Desired Configuration to download and run
$dscConfig = @{
  "wmfVersion" = "latest";
  "configuration" = @{
    "url" = "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-automation-configurations/raw/master/dsc.zip";
    "script" = "configure-http.ps1";
    "function" = "WebsiteTest";
  };
}

# Get information about the scale set
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss `
                -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
                -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet"

# Add the Desired State Configuration extension to install IIS and configure basic website
$vmss = Add-AzureRmVmssExtension `
    -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss `
    -Publisher Microsoft.Powershell `
    -Type DSC `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 2.24 `
    -Name "DSC" `
    -Setting $dscConfig

# Update the scale set and apply the Desired State Configuration extension to the VM instances
Update-AzureRmVmss `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
    -Name "myScaleSet"  `
    -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```